# How come I have 4 li elements but I'm seeing 5 on my page?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery and I'm trying to build a game in my free time for good practice. I'm almost finished with it, however I'm running into a continuous issue. In my html I'm giving the li's I don't want shown yet a class hidden. then I'm using `$('givenID).removeClass('hidden')` when I want my li to appear. However I don't understand why I have an extra numbered list item. Any suggestions this is my html code...

```
<ol id="rulesList">
    <li style="color:black">Check off your favorite models
        <br>
        <strong style="color:white">YOU CAN ONLY SELECT THREE!!!</strong>
    </li>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    <!--Don't display the third rule until the the user selects the favorite images -->
    <li class="hidden" id="second-rule">Now rate your favorite models.
        <strong>
          (DON'T GIVE TWO IMAGES THE SAME RATING!!)
        </strong>
    </li>
    <li style="color:white" class="hidden" id="third-rule">
        <strong>Last step, Guess her nationality!!</strong>
        <li>
            <li class="hidden" id="fourth-rule">
                <strong>THANKS   'FA'  PLAYIN  ;)</strong>
            </li>
        </li>
    </li>
</ol>
```

There isn't 5 li elements??///

[image]

Comment: You forgot the slash in the closing li tag of the 3rd list item, thus accidentally creating a new item.

Comment: *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](/help/mcve) before posting."*

Comment: Because you provided invalid HTML and the browser did its best to guess what you actually meant.

Answer (score 5):

This is a common pattern. Instead of closing an `<li>` element you opened another:

```
<li style="color:white" class="hidden" id="third-rule"><strong>...</strong><li>
```

This is why nesting things properly so that you can see all opening and closing tags plainly while scrolling is important. Mistakes like this happen. Keep them as obvious as possible.

Fix it like this:

```
<li style="color:white" class="hidden" id="third-rule">
  <strong>...</strong>
</li>
```

Now it's really obvious it's done correctly. The more HTML you do the more you'll come to expect things to look like this, and that missing `/` will stand out as a mistake.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple of a mistake. I should of checked for typography errors before going to this extreme, thank you @tadman !!

Comment: Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

You've opened a new `li` element instead of closing it. Replace this `<li>` with this `</li>`